# Importing data from another workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help, cant figure out how to import only values with this code

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As range
    Dim rngDestination As range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa; *.xls"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.range("A2:C200")
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DS").range("G17:G17")
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook for file containing this code.
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa; *.xls"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        
            'Just reference the files - no need to activate them first.
            Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
            wkbSourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C200").Copy 'Remember to change the sheet name.
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Worksheets("DS").Range("G17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
            'For a normal Copy/Paste you can use:
            'wkbSourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C200").Copy _
            '    Destination:=wkbCrntWorkBook.Worksheets("DS").Range("G17")
            
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
            
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I use it to automatically import files from bunch of excels, thats why i didn't wont to use sheet name, i have over 800 files in one folder and this code extract data from them, i will try it tomorrow and let you know if it worked, tnx.

Comment: You can also reference the sheet by index number, so if you know it will always be the first sheet you can use `Sheets(1)`.

Comment: It works, with just a bit modification so i dont question about large amount of data in clipboard, tnx :)